# Error showing at npm start but then runs smoothly... [MongoError: Topology closed]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have this website in Express-Node/MongoDb, managed to install it and have it run smoothly with no errors whatsoever. Then, as you do, I updated 3 miserable files, added a couple of lines of code, nothing fancy (worked locally as well), updated everything on the live server and after the npm start got the error message below (multiple times, everytime I make a call to the db I guess).

```
MongoDB connection error: MongoError: Topology closed
at NativeTopology.close (/home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:325:38)
at /home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:267:21
at maybePromise (/home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:719:3)
at MongoClient.close (/home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:248:10)
at /home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:711:20
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:709:19)
at Mongoose.connect (/home/jelastic/ROOT/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:335:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jelastic/ROOT/controllers/visitController.js:7:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jelastic/ROOT/routes/activity.js:4:24)
```

I check my connection credentials to the db, everything seems ok... but hey, sometimes you forget a period, a parenthesis, whatever... so I rollback to a previous working version and... got the same error. What's weird too is that the site works just fine as far as I can see. Everything loads fine, I was able to insert new documents to collections, delete some... No error shows up in the console after the the initial display.

I don't get it. What could possibly trigger this error if I ruled out my code?? I don't like it when I get an error that seems blocking yet everything seems to work fine...

Any insight would be much appreciated!!